# cSlider: stop autoplay on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

How can I stop the autoplay function of cSlider with an onmouseover event?

HTML:

```
<div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">

   <div class="da-slide">
     <p>Text</p>
   </div>

   <div class="da-slide">
     <p>More text</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

What I have tried so far with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#da-slider').cslider({
            autoplay    : true,
            bgincrement : 450
    });
});

$('#da-slider').hover(function() {

    if($('#daslider').autoplay('true')){
        autoplay: false
    }

}, function () {
    autoplay: true
});
```

This is the one I'm using:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature not implemented by default but this shouldn't stop you from implementing it on your own. Look at modified plugin code below (draw attention on `stop` and 'start' methods)

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    /*
    * Slider object.
    */
    $.Slider = function (options, element) {

        this.$el = $(element);

        this._init(options);

    };

    $.Slider.defaults = {
        current: 0,     // index of current slide
        bgincrement: 50, // increment the bg position (parallax effect) when sliding
        autoplay: false, // slideshow on / off
        interval: 4000  // time between transitions
    };

    $.Slider.prototype = {
        _init: function (options) {

            this.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.Slider.defaults, options);

            this.$slides = this.$el.children('div.da-slide');
            this.slidesCount = this.$slides.length;

            this.current = this.options.current;

            if (this.current < 0 || this.current >= this.slidesCount) {

                this.current = 0;

            }

            this.$slides.eq(this.current).addClass('da-slide-current');

            var $navigation = $('<nav class="da-dots"/>');
            for (var i = 0; i < this.slidesCount; ++i) {

                $navigation.append('<span/>');

            }
            $navigation.appendTo(this.$el);

            this.$pages = this.$el.find('nav.da-dots > span');
            this.$navNext = this.$el.find('span.da-arrows-next');
            this.$navPrev = this.$el.find('span.da-arrows-prev');

            this.isAnimating = false;

            this.bgpositer = 0;

            this.cssAnimations = Modernizr.cssanimations;
            this.cssTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

            if (!this.cssAnimations || !this.cssAnimations) {

                this.$el.addClass('da-slider-fb');

            }

            this._updatePage();

            // load the events
            this._loadEvents();

            // slideshow
            if (this.options.autoplay) {

                this._startSlideshow();

            }

        },
        _navigate: function (page, dir) {

            var $current = this.$slides.eq(this.current), $next, _self = this;

            if (this.current === page || this.isAnimating) return false;

            this.isAnimating = true;

            // check dir
            var classTo, classFrom, d;

            if (!dir) {

                (page > this.current) ? d = 'next' : d = 'prev';

            }
            else {

                d = dir;

            }

            if (this.cssAnimations && this.cssAnimations) {

                if (d === 'next') {

                    classTo = 'da-slide-toleft';
                    classFrom = 'da-slide-fromright';
                    ++this.bgpositer;

                }
                else {

                    classTo = 'da-slide-toright';
                    classFrom = 'da-slide-fromleft';
                    --this.bgpositer;

                }

                this.$el.css('background-position', this.bgpositer * this.options.bgincrement + '% 0%');

            }

            this.current = page;

            $next = this.$slides.eq(this.current);

            if (this.cssAnimations && this.cssAnimations) {

                var rmClasses = 'da-slide-toleft da-slide-toright da-slide-fromleft da-slide-fromright';
                $current.removeClass(rmClasses);
                $next.removeClass(rmClasses);

                $current.addClass(classTo);
                $next.addClass(classFrom);

                $current.removeClass('da-slide-current');
                $next.addClass('da-slide-current');

            }

            // fallback
            if (!this.cssAnimations || !this.cssAnimations) {

                $next.css('left', (d === 'next') ? '100%' : '-100%').stop().animate({
                    left: '0%'
                }, 1000, function () {
                    _self.isAnimating = false;
                });

                $current.stop().animate({
                    left: (d === 'next') ? '-100%' : '100%'
                }, 1000, function () {
                    $current.removeClass('da-slide-current');
                });

            }

            this._updatePage();

        },
        _updatePage: function () {

            this.$pages.removeClass('da-dots-current');
            this.$pages.eq(this.current).addClass('da-dots-current');

        },
        _startSlideshow: function () {

            var _self = this;

            this.slideshow = setTimeout(function () {

                var page = (_self.current < _self.slidesCount - 1) ? page = _self.current + 1 : page = 0;
                _self._navigate(page, 'next');

                if (_self.options.autoplay) {

                    _self._startSlideshow();

                }

            }, this.options.interval);

        },
        page: function (idx) {

            if (idx >= this.slidesCount || idx < 0) {

                return false;

            }

            if (this.options.autoplay) {

                clearTimeout(this.slideshow);
                this.options.autoplay = false;

            }

            this._navigate(idx);

        },
        stop: function () {
            if (this.options.autoplay) {

                clearTimeout(this.slideshow);
                this.options.autoplay = false;

            }
        },
        start: function () {
            this.options.autoplay = true;
            this._startSlideshow();
        },
        _loadEvents: function () {

            var _self = this;

            this.$pages.on('click.cslider', function (event) {

                _self.page($(this).index());
                return false;

            });

            this.$navNext.on('click.cslider', function (event) {

                if (_self.options.autoplay) {

                    clearTimeout(_self.slideshow);
                    _self.options.autoplay = false;

                }

                var page = (_self.current < _self.slidesCount - 1) ? page = _self.current + 1 : page = 0;
                _self._navigate(page, 'next');
                return false;

            });

            this.$navPrev.on('click.cslider', function (event) {

                if (_self.options.autoplay) {

                    clearTimeout(_self.slideshow);
                    _self.options.autoplay = false;

                }

                var page = (_self.current > 0) ? page = _self.current - 1 : page = _self.slidesCount - 1;
                _self._navigate(page, 'prev');
                return false;

            });

            if (this.cssTransitions) {

                if (!this.options.bgincrement) {

                    this.$el.on('webkitAnimationEnd.cslider animationend.cslider OAnimationEnd.cslider', function (event) {

                        if (event.originalEvent.animationName === 'toRightAnim4' || event.originalEvent.animationName === 'toLeftAnim4') {

                            _self.isAnimating = false;

                        }

                    });

                }
                else {

                    this.$el.on('webkitTransitionEnd.cslider transitionend.cslider OTransitionEnd.cslider', function (event) {

                        if (event.target.id === _self.$el.attr('id'))
                            _self.isAnimating = false;

                    });

                }

            }

        }
    };

    var logError = function (message) {
        if (this.console) {
            console.error(message);
        }
    };

    $.fn.cslider = function (options) {

        if (typeof options === 'string') {

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

            this.each(function () {

                var instance = $.data(this, 'cslider');

                if (!instance) {
                    logError("cannot call methods on cslider prior to initialization; " +
                    "attempted to call method '" + options + "'");
                    return;
                }

                if (!$.isFunction(instance[options]) || options.charAt(0) === "_") {
                    logError("no such method '" + options + "' for cslider instance");
                    return;
                }

                instance[options].apply(instance, args);

            });

        }
        else {

            this.each(function () {

                var instance = $.data(this, 'cslider');
                if (!instance) {
                    $.data(this, 'cslider', new $.Slider(options, this));
                }
            });

        }

        return this;

    };

})(jQuery);
```

With updated plugin you can pause and renew autiplaying with this code:

```
$('#da-slider').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).cslider("stop");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).cslider("start");
    }
);
```