# Parallax content slider autoplay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, parallax

Parallax content slider works once, but then fails to work, without any error. here is the example http://vilamihu.didacticmedia.ro/ , and here are the important bits of code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"></script>
    <!--end slider -->
    <!---strat-date-piker---->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker,#datepicker1").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
    <!---/End-date-piker---->
    <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/JFGrid.css" />-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/JFFormStyle-1.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JFCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JFForms.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
```

Those are in `<head>`. Here is the body:

```
 <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
        <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="da-img">
                <img src="images/slideprimu.jpg" alt="" class="class1" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="da-img">
                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" class="class1"/>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="da-img">
                <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" class="class1"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="da-img">
                <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="" class="class1"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="da-img">
                <img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="" class="class1"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="da-img">
                <img src="images/slide5.jpg" alt="" class="class1"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="da-img">
                <img src="images/slide6.jpg" alt="" class="class1"/></div>
        </div>

        <!--/slide -->
    </div>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#da-slider').cslider({

            current: 4,
            // index of current slide

            bgincrement: 50,
            // increment the background position
            // (parallax effect) when sliding
            circular: true,
            autoplay: true,
            // slideshow on / off

            interval: 500
            // time between transitions

        });
    });
```

Note: the links to photos are good. if I change the "current" setting, then it will start at that photo, go once, and stop. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: your website is not avalable

Comment: Yes, i know, the contract just expired, and will pay it in a couple of days..sorry

Comment: You site is working again (yeah!), but you have not spelled out how to reproduce the problem. Which page and what actions will cause it?

Comment: Simple. enter the first page and observe the slider! it switches a photo, and that is it. there are 6 pictures loaded in the slider. but only one transition works

Comment: Have you referred [Old Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341448/cslider-stop-autoplay-on-mouseover)

Comment: I have the same problem... IntervalSec and bgincrement 0 did not work... did you find any answer since... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#da-slider').cslider({

        current: 4,
        // index of current slide

        bgincrement: 50,
        // increment the background position
        // (parallax effect) when sliding
        circular: true,
        autoplay: true,
        // slideshow on / off

        intervalSec: 500
        // time between transitions

    });
});
```

I have just changed name of value `interval` to `intervalSec`

as per the [documentation](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Super-Tiny-Cross-fading-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-CSS3-cslider.html) other things should be okay

Also in the provided link of website you are using older version of jQuery v1.8.3
If possible update it to latest version [CDN](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js), as for CSS3 newer version works better(Note: which does not support some old browsers)

Update: In the given website Link there are two JQuery UI of different versions used

1. [jQuery-UI 1.9.2](http://vilamihu.didacticmedia.ro/js/jquery-ui.js)
2. [jQuery-UI 1.9.1](http://vilamihu.didacticmedia.ro/js/jquery-ui.min.js)

Please remove the older version(the js/jquery-ui.min.js) to avoid any conflict..

Comment: Will try with new version of jquery

Comment: Also one more thing, your site is calling jquery-UI and jqueryUI.min both i.e. it is called twice, so remove one instance

Comment: The Online version now changes one or two image then stops, So I think its internal jquery conflict try removing one of the two UI that should help

Comment: I used another slider in the end..Will give you the bounty anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

today I was trying to solve exactly the same problem.

Even though this answer is probably not required anymore, I will add it for further coders that will encounter the same problem.

The root cause is in **bgincrement** value. If there is no background that it can "move" it will stop responding without any error. And its total mess.

Setting **bgincrement** to zero made the slider work again:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#da-slider').cslider({
        autoplay    : true,
        bgincrement : 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... please deactivate all other jquery plugins, let only the slider at place. Do not forget to delete the initiation codes in your custom js file or in your html file as well ! Normally your slider works online after all. 
Then you can re-add your plugins step by step and you will recognize with which plugin your slider has incompatibility. I had jQuery Timelinr 0.9.54 plugin which blocked my slider.