# parallax content slider works locally but not online

Tags: jquery, slider, css-animations

I am just in the beginning of the works on a website but i am already sticking on the first problem since some days... i use the [Parallax Content Slider from Codrops website](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/).

When i test locally on my computer, it works fine but when it is online, it stops at the second slide and it does not move anymore and it does not work with the navigation either. Tested on Firefox and Google Chrome, it has the same problem on both.

What i do not understand the most is that why it works until the second slide ?

HTML :

```
<div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
    <div class="da-slide">
        <h1>MK Architecture - About</h1>
        <p>Nulla facilisi. Phasellus cursus nisl id sapien accumsan, et laoreet neque porta....</p>
        <div class="da-img">
            <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="MKA about" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="da-slide">
        <h1>Services - Let me work...</h1>
        <p>Nulla facilisi. Phasellus cursus nisl id sapien accumsan, et laoreet neque porta...</p>
        <p class="da-link">Go to Service section</p>
        <div class="da-img">
            <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="MKA services" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The connected CSS files :
main : http://igorlaszlo.com/mk/index.css
slider : http://igorlaszlo.com/mk/slider.css

The connected jQuery files :
main : http://igorlaszlo.com/mk/js/custom.js
slider : http://igorlaszlo.com/mk/js/slider.js

Do someone has an idea what blocks my slider after the second slide ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer... if you will have the same problem ([as there are some others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493448/parallax-content-slider-autoplay-not-working)), please deactivate all other jquery plugins, let only the slider. Do not forget also to delete the initiation codes in your custom js file or in your html file ! You will see, your slider works very well online. Then you can re-add your plugins step by step and you will recognize with which plugin your slider has incompatibility. 
I had jQuery Timelinr 0.9.54 plugin which blocked my slider.